# showing that an infinite series converge

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

im trying to prove that the infinite seires :
[image: this series]

converges. ive managed to show that it does not absloutly converge. i cant use Dirichlet's test and i cant use Abel's test since that series dosent meet the demands of the theorems. any ideas? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$|\frac {3^{n}+4^{n}} {2^{n}+(-1)^{n} 5^{n}}| \leq \frac {(4.5)^{n}+(4.5)^{n}} {5^{n}-2^{n}} <\frac {2 ((4.5)^{n})} {5^{n}-\frac  1  25^{n}}$. Can you finish?

Answer (score 1):

The series (with terms $a_n$) is absolutely convergent:
$$
|a_n|\le \frac{2\cdot 4^n}{5^n-2^n}\le (4/5)^n
$$

Comment: thank you very much.